# please anybody tell me ,cordova 3.5.1 is nessary insteed i am using 3.5.0 jar file

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

please reply,
I want to upgrade my eclipse phone gap project
Currently my project full filled 3.5.0 version but due to have some technical issues I could not published in google play console

so  please many body tell me how and from where to download Cordova-3.5.1.jar file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a list of all available cordova versions by using this command in your shell:

```
npm view cordova versions
```

To install a specific version, here version 5.1.1, use this command in the shell:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@5.1.1
```

Here is the documentation: [Updating Cordova and Your Project](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide/cli/index.html#link-11)